# XenForo - How can I make a directory visible to visitors?

Tags: xenforo

I have a XenForo board and I want to put some files on the system, for everyone to see. So I created a directory and uploaded files. When I am trying to access it though I am getting a 403 error Forbidden error in the browser. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Htaccess file and check if there is an access restriction for the folder where the files are located.